# Dynamically adding and removing AngularJS templates, while scoping the CSS narrowly

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate

So I have a few different templates which get put into `ng-view`, and each template is animated into being using the slick new `ng-animate` directive. Each template has its own CSS, and I need to figure out a way to prevent the CSS from colliding, so that an h1 declaration in template1 only applies to template1, and not template2.

The options for which I'm currently aware are either to rewrite the CSS as it's about to be served to the page to target a parent element, which I could define as an ID which matches the template. The other, less desirable option is to use iframes, which means i'd have several instances of the app running at once, each in their own iframe.

Are there any other options out there? Which way is best to solve the goal of isolating each CSS declaration?

Comment: +1 for using concrete ids for each template. Also to prevent collisions with other elements in the web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your controller assign a body className and use that to scope out the CSS styles per template.